# Oracle 12c Number field mapped to DT_WSTR in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I am trying to extract the data from Oracle 12c database table to flat file using Microsoft SSIS 2008.

**Table in Oracle Database**

```
Create Table Test
(
  Col1 Varchar2(10),
  Col2 NUMBER default 0
)
```

There is no precision / scale is specified for the Col2 Number field. So it is storing the values as given.

**Sample values**

[image]

**SSIS Package:**

In SSIS package in OLEDB source component, we mapped the table and Col2 is mapped with DT_WSTR. And if i am changing to DT_Numeric, i am not sure on what to specify in the precision and scale. Since there is no precision / scale mentioned in Oracle table.

**EDIT :**

I am getting the error in OLE DB Source itself in the "Execute Phase" itself,
[OLE DB Source [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGEp2.png)] Error: There was an error with output column "COL2" (20) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (11).
The column status returned was: "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".

[image]

If i modify the data type in Output Columns of OLE DB Source like below, it is working, I have not modified in External Columns and OLE DB Error Output columns. In both the places it is DT_WSTR. Is this is ok?

And also i have not touched anything in Flat File Destination since i am getting exception in OLE DB Source.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, when precision/scale is not explicitly included, the type NUMBER defaults to float:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT313

so changing the DT_WSTR to DT_R8 (double-precision float) should be the safest assumption, you can do this in advanced editor:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and immediate help. I have placed few screenshots in the "Edit" section of Question.
I am getting the error in OLE DB Source itself in the "Execute Phase" itself,
[OLE DB Source [1]] Error: There was an error with output column "COL2" (20) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (11). 
The column status returned was: "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page." 
As you suggested, it is working, If i modify the data type in Output Columns of OLE DB Source to DT_R8

Comment: I have not modified in External Columns and OLE DB Error Output columns. In both the places it is DT_WSTR. Is this is ok?.   And also i have not touched anything in Flat File Destination since i am getting exception in OLE DB Source.

Comment: You can do the transformation at any point, I didn't do it at source in my example because I don't have an oracle connection, but you can do it as you show in the Edit section. Then you might need to remap the fields in the flat file destination and it will sort itself out, without the need to change data types explicitly. Worst case scenario you can just delete and recreate the flat file destination.

Comment: Thanks. I marked your answer. In OLEDB Source, I only changed to DT_R8 in the Output columns and not changed in the External columns and OLEDB Source Error Output. is that ok?  i am new to SSIS. That is the reason asking this again

Comment: OLEDB source advance editor, is doing implicit conversion. To avoid OLE DB source error, we can only do Advance editor modification. To fix this issue, we can't use the Data Conversion in between the OLE DB Source and Flat File. Is my understanding is correct?

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. Your understanding is correct in that you are overriding the implicitly derived data type in Advance Editor, but technically you can also do it by Data Conversion or Derived Column. In this page you can see which conversions are valid, thankfully, DT_WSTR can cast to any other data type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/cast-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15